# Why only shared resistances are taken into consideration while computing Elmore delay?

Tags: integrated-circuit, vlsi, timing-analysis, cad

While we compute the delay , using Elmore delay model we take into consideration the shared resistance and capacitance. I would like to know why are we only concerned with shared resistance not the other resistances.

Answer (score 1):

Because, **by definition**, the (shared) **path** resistance(s) determines the **path** delay. So, resistors not on the path from root to sink are not taken into account.

Check the slide "RC tree definitions" in this [slide show](http://www.brown.edu/Departments/Engineering/Courses/engn1600/Lectures/EN160-10-complexGateOptimization.pdf).
(\$ A \cap B \$ means the set that contains all those elements that A and B have in common.)

The solution in the slide is:
$$ \tau_{Di} = \sum^{N}_{k=1} C_k \cdot R_{ik} =$$
$$ C_1 \cdot R_1 + C_2 \cdot R_1 + C_3 \cdot (R_1+R_3) + C_4 \cdot (R_1+R_3) + C_i \cdot (R_1+R_3+R_i)$$

Note that using the definition given on the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elmore_delay), *"summing the delays through each segment as the R (electrical resistance) times the downstream C"*,  gives the same result.
$$ R_1 \cdot (C_1+C_2+C_3+C_4+C_i) + R_3 \cdot (C_3+C_4+C_i) + R_i \cdot C_i $$

Comment: the definition is okay, but why only the capacitances of the branches are taken into account and not also the resistances? could you explain it in other words please? I am not sure if i understood it