# Elmore delay resistances

Tags: passive-networks, delay

I know this question has already been asked [enter link description here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/426823/why-only-shared-resistances-are-taken-into-consideration-while-computing-elmore), but honestly I did not find the answer exhaustive, so I am going to ask it again, in a more specific way.

1. WHY in the Elmore delay model, if I have a tree like the one below, only Resistances belonging to the main path are taken into account (please don't give the formula of Elmore delay, I know what a shared resistance is, I would like to understand the reason behind it) ?
   [image]
2. WHY only Capacitances belonging to "branches" are taken into account ( please same as before) ?
3. If a branch is composed of more than 1 RC L-segment, for example 2 RC L-segment (like a second order low pass filter to be clear), can one still neglect the Resistances? And the capacitances will have to be summed?
4. If the branch itself itself is another tree, as in the picture below, can one still apply what holds for the previous case or extra considerations must be taken into account? [image]